# Sed characters (") won't pass through loop

Tags: sed, awk

I wrote some kind of script which grabs strings from array and replays it in file. The problem here that special characters wont pass through. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash/
NewParameters=(
scservice.memberServiceEndpoint="http://mywebhere.com"
scservice.memberServiceConpoint="http://example.com"
play.modules.disabled += "play.data.format.FormattersModule"
)

file=/home/conf.conf

for i in "${NewParameters[@]}"                                                           
do
     before=$(printf "%s\n" $i | awk -F'=' '{print $1}')                              
        after=$(printf "%s\n" $i | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')                               
            sed -i "s@$before=.*@$before=$after@g" $file
done
```

Output result:

```
scservice.memberServiceEndpoint=http://mywebhere.com
scservice.memberServiceConpoint=http://example.com
play.modules.disabled += play.data.format.FormattersModule
```

Comment: Why didn't you quote `i` in the printf statements?

Comment: Does it need to be quoted? I am still learning bash :)

Comment: will, since you haven't quoted the array entries, I suppose it's too late to worry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are removed by the shell in the assignment already in the "quote removal" phase (see `man bash` for details). Backslash the double quote, or single quote the whole elements. Also, the last line in NewParameters is in fact three elements separated by spaces; again, if you want to have everything in one element, backslash the spaces or enclose the whole line into single quotes.

Comment: Auch, that's the problem, single quotes for the whole element worked for (").  But the play.modules.disabled +=  is tricky, because I don't want to check every time which the line has or has not spaces and add again ' ' :?